# Trying to consume a REST API with inconsistent data types in response

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm currently trying to consume a REST API in Java to return a list of objects. I've created a model for the object in Java like so:

```
public class PersonApiModel {
    private int id;
    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;
    private String email;
    private String ip_address;
    private long latitude;
    private long longitude;
}
```

I'm using a RestTemplate to make the call (have removed the reference to the endpoint for security):

```
private final String baseUri = "XXXX";
private final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    public ResponseEntity getAllUsersInLondon() {
        try {
            return restTemplate.exchange(
                    baseUri + "city/London/users",
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    null,
                    new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<PersonApiModel>>(){}
            );
        } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }
```

However, while my model uses the Long data type for the latitude and longitude, there are a few entries in the response which return String values. The third entry here is an example:

```
[
    {
        "id": 135,
        "first_name": "Mechelle",
        "last_name": "Boam",
        "email": "mboam3q@thetimes.co.uk",
        "ip_address": "113.71.242.187",
        "latitude": -6.5115909,
        "longitude": 105.652983
    },
    {
        "id": 396,
        "first_name": "Terry",
        "last_name": "Stowgill",
        "email": "tstowgillaz@webeden.co.uk",
        "ip_address": "143.190.50.240",
        "latitude": -6.7098551,
        "longitude": 111.3479498
    },
    {
        "id": 520,
        "first_name": "Andrew",
        "last_name": "Seabrocke",
        "email": "aseabrockeef@indiegogo.com",
        "ip_address": "28.146.197.176",
        "latitude": "27.69417",
        "longitude": "109.73583"
    },
]
```

Of course, when trying to run this, I get the following error:

```
HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `long` from String "27.69417": not a valid Long value
```

I'm a bit unsure on how to proceed here. I know I need to use the Long.parseLong(str) method here but unsure where to do it.

1. Should I be allowing multiple data types in my object data model?
2. Should I be converting the String to Long as I receive the response?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store latitude and longitude, shouldn't that be a `float`? I think that would solve the problem, as the literal values would be converted into floats straight away, and the `String` values would be converted with `Float.parseFloat(String)`.

#### Edit

If you really want to deserialize into a `Long`, you can use the jackson `@JsonDeserialize` annotation. You can find an example [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations#5-jsondeserialize).